# Visual studio code default quickfix keybinding not working on Fedora 35?

Tags: linux, fedora, operating-systems, visual-studio-code

I have upgraded to Fedora 35 recently.

While coding on Visual Studio Code, I can't use the Shortcut <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>.</kbd> to open the quick fix.

When I press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>.</kbd> it always display the letter <kbd>e</kbd> with the underline. Typing anything more does not work except press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>.</kbd> again or press <kbd>Esc</kbd>.

I have try to use that key combination in the browser, the terminal when typing to make sure it is not the VSCode problem. And it happens exactly the same.

I have found this shortcut in the `Settings` but not getting any result.

I still think this is the shortcut problem but don't know how to find which program use that shortcut, which affects the whole system.

Please tell me how to find which program create this shortcut, or is it a bug?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The e with an underline lets you insert an emoji by typing its name after the e. Try `ctrl+alt+.` to bypass this. It worked for me.

Comment: Sadly. The `Ctrl+alt+.` does nothing for me.

Comment: You are right about the emoji. I have figured it out and posted the fix as the answer below. Anyway, I still want to give you the green check because you have shown me the way :)

Answer (score 6):

I still can't fix this, but I found a workaround.

I have changed the `editor.action.quickfix` keybinding in VSCode to another keybinding to use the VSCode quickfix.

### Update

I have figured out that the key combination will trigger the emoji typing on Fedora.

Here are the steps to fix this:

1. Open `ibus-setup`
2. Select `Emoji` tab
3. Click on the `...` in Emoji Annotation
4. Change the keycode and the modifiers to anything you want
5. Click `Apply` then `OK`

Now the conflict is gone :)

Comment: Can confirm that this did the trick for me under Ubuntu 22.04 as well.

Comment: This worked on Ubuntu for me too. There was actually two bindings: `CTRL + .` and `CTRL + ;` so I just removed the `CTRL + .` one.

Comment: Ubuntu 22.04, the ibus-setup thing worked like a charm